# Instance reference/ Linking in webapi 2.0

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How do you do restful instance referencing in webapi 2?

An object often have references to instances of other objects. For example a blogpost has a reference to the author who created the post.

```
public class Blogpost {
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public string Text {get; set;}
   public Author Author {get; set;}
}
```

The RESTful principle, according to [this video @ 45:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdSrT4yjS1g#t=2720)is to converted to the reference to a direct URI. Something like this:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Title": "My first blogpost",
  "Text": "Hello World",
  "Author": [ "href" : "http://app.com/api/authors/4"]
}
```

How is this supposed to be done in webapi 2? By default if you disable lazy loading, references are just returned as an empty array:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Title": "My first blogpost",
  "Text": "Hello World",
  "Author": []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a built-in way to do this task, but you can get what you want using a custom contract resolver, a custom value provider and using an interface or base class on your entities.

**Entity base class:**
Probably your entities already have a base class defining the common Id property, if don't, just create the base class and change the entities class to inherit from DomainEntityBase.

```
public abstract class DomainEntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Custom contract resolver:**
We'll use a custom contract resolver to change the value provider of referenced entities.

```
public class ReferenceLinkContractResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    #region Methods
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        var childProperties = properties.Where(p => typeof(DomainEntityBase).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));

        foreach (var c in childProperties)
        {
        c.ValueProvider = new ReferenceLinkingValueProvider(ReflectionHelper.GetProperty(type, c.PropertyName));
        }

        return properties;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Custom value provider:**
With this custom value provider we change the reference entity serialization to the href property.

```
public class ReferenceLinkingValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    #region Fields
    private PropertyInfo m_property;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public ReferenceLinkingValueProvider(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        m_property = property;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public object GetValue(object target)
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var value = m_property.GetValue(target);
        var entity = value as DomainEntityBase;

        if (entity == null)
        {
        return value;
        }

        // If your resources are in plural, you will need some helper method 
        // to put in right plural (remember the resources with 'y' ends).
        var resourceName = entity.GetType().Name;

        // Here is where the real work happens. You change the entire entity
        // serialization to just the href property.
        return new
        {
        href = "http://app.com/api/{0}/{1}".With(resourceName, entity.Id)
        };
    }

    public void SetValue(object target, object value)
    {
        m_property.SetValue(target, value);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Now, on your web api config, set the ContractResolver of your json formatter:**

```
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new ReferenceLinkContractResolver();
```

> Note: some helper and extensions methods, like the "With" one, come
>   from the [HelperSharp](https://github.com/giacomelli/HelperSharp) library.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. Is this something you are using yourself? I find it strange that there is so little documentation/information on this topic.

Comment: Yes, I've create it for a specific situation, in my case I serialize the Href and Id property too.

Comment: Followup @giacomelli. How do you handle collections? For example a Author has a "ICollection<Blogpost> blogposts", which in the perfect world should be http://app.com/api/authors/4/blogposts"